# x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:2:2 ,with ffmpeg php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, drupal-6, ffmpeg-php, amazon-elastic-transcoder

[image]

Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!

Comment: Although you _may_ be invoking this through Drupal and thus PHP, your sample is CLI only, so I don’t think those two are related to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i ResizedImg/Default.jpg -i Chem_XII_L1_Ch2_The_Solid_State_Seg_-_6.mp3  -y -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -c:s mov_text -strict experimental -vprofile baseline -level 2  -threads 0 out5.mp4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).